# swap files created when I open a new frame

Tags: frames

When I use `C-x 5 2`, it opens a new frame showing the same file that I'm already editing. So, every time I open a new frame, I get an unwanted need to "swap" to another file. Is there a way to get around this?
Thanks.

Comment: The question is unclear - underspecified.  Just what buffer (file) do you want displayed in the new (or the already existing) frame? You don't want the same buffer - that's all you've said so far.

Answer (score 1):

Found it! `find-file-other-frame` (`C-x 5 f`) works nicely.